# how to use the total property in highcharts point

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

Can you please demonstrate a use case for this property in the pie chart:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.total
How it can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/tu67e1ce/

```
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>, Total: {point.total}'
    },
```

Hover any of the slices, and see total value in the tooltip. You can also use that value in the data labels formatter etc.

Comment: As I understand there is no need to set it up?

Comment: Indeed, it is just calculated option, when using pie chart or charts with stacking. It is rather "read-only" option.